# How to grab a copy of the icon a program uses using Python

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I am designing a program where the user can type in the file path to a program. And then once the user has entered a file path that exists my program will grab a copy of the icon of that file. I have searched around online but I have not found much of anything. Is there a way to do this using python? If so how?

Comment: why not just manually go and get the icon. you could do a search of the file path using the os module but different programs use different names for pictures.

Comment: @NendoTaka I have done this where I search the programs folder that contains it and all that programs contents and then searched for all .ico files and a majority of the time I did not find the .ico that the program uses to display for the application icon.

Comment: not all images are icons for instance google chrome uses pngs

Comment: @NendoTaka I will implement that into my program to search for image files to. But I am using Mozilla Firefox in my example and I can not find the image that it uses for its icon. I figured that the icon is stored in the .exe program itself. How could I copy that out of the file. Because when I create a shortcut of it and click change icon for the shortcut it showed the icon path to just be the .exe file itself.

Comment: pulling any information out of a .exe file is hard. .exe files are made so that you can't just view the code but the image itself should not be in the .exe because that is just a compiled version of the code the image should be somewhere in the file path but finding it may be difficult

Comment: @NendoTaka I was able to find a little code snippet that seems to work. It uses the win32api.

Comment: It depends on whether the icon is stored externally or internally. If it's a base64-encoded image inside the applications code, it won't be easy to find.